# Disable controls during get Json

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, json

In ASP.NET MVC, I'm using JSON and jquery to get data for a chart. Is there a way to disable controls and set cursor to wait while data is loading and chart is drawing?
An abstract of my code is

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     $(document).ready(function () {
            $.getJSON(
                '@Url.Action("JsonPlot", "Home")',
                function (chartData) {
                    var plot1 = $.jqplot('chartdiv', [points], {...});
           });              
        });
</script>
```

Where can I put

```
$("*").attr("disabled", "disabled");
$('body').css('cursor', 'wait');
```

and then

```
$("*").removeAttr('disabled');
$('body').css('cursor', 'auto');
```

?

Thanks!

Comment: why `$("*")`? universal selector is too slow.

Comment: @undefined Thanks! Besides, `$("*")` didn't worked properly so I narrowed to `$("input"), $("select")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To take full advantage of the jQuery AJAX callbacks, you should use `$.ajax`:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '@Url.Action("JsonPlot", "Home")',
    dataType: 'json',
    beforeSend: function() {
        /* Disable UI */
    },
    success: function( data ) {
        /* Update UI using server response */
    },
    complete: function() {
        /* Enable UI again, regardless of whether 
           server call was successful or not*/
    },
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus) {
        /* Display error message to user */
    }

});
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$("*").attr("disabled", "disabled");
$('body').css('cursor', 'wait');

            $.getJSON(
                '@Url.Action("JsonPlot", "Home")',
                success:function (chartData) {
                    var plot1 = $.jqplot('chartdiv', [points], {...});
                     $("*").removeAttr('disabled');
                     $('body').css('cursor', 'auto');

           });              
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery methods: ajaxStart() and ajaxStop() for that.